# Series obtained by product of Fourier coefficients of a modular form is again a modular form?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_f(n)e^{2\pi inz}$ and $g(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_g(n)e^{2\pi inz}$ be two modular forms of integer weight $k$ for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Consider
$$ h(z) := \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_f(n)a_g(n)e^{2\pi inz}. $$
*Question: Is $h(z)$ again a modular form (possibly of different weight, $2k$)?*

I guess one can use Hecke's converse theorem, but I'm unable to check the analytic continuation of the completed Gamma function
$$ \Lambda_{h}(s) := (2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_f(n)a_g(n)n^{-s}, $$
nor if it satisfies the functional equation of the form
$$ \Lambda_{h}(s) = i^{2k} \Lambda_{h}(2k-s). $$

If this is not true, I could not come up with any easy counter example also.

Comment: No, $h(z)$ is in general not a modular form. In fact, the $L$-function that you created is essentially (but not quite) the Rankin-Selberg $L$-function of $f \otimes g$. This is associated to an automorphic form on $\mathrm{SL}_4(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathrm{SL}_4(\mathbb{R}) / \mathrm{SO}(4)$ rather than on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R}) / \mathrm{SO}(2) = \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}) \backslash \mathbb{H}$.